# Start Excel disabling all AddOns?

Tags: excel

Im having an addon for Excel which requires my company's server to open. However if I want to open Excel from home at my work computer, it'll crash due to said addon not having access to the Company server.

Is it possible to disabvle the addon without having to open Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that by starting Excel in safemode.

Create a shortcut to Excel and then open the properties window via right-click on the shortcut. Go to the end of the "target" line and add `/s` behind the quotation marks.